# machine name resolution over SMB on windows

Tags: smb, cifs

In order to resolve IP to hostname on my environment, I can do it by 3 ways:
DNS, Netbios and SMB.
to test DNS i use "ping -a IPAddress",
To test netbios i use "nbtstat ",

How can i test smb ? I know there is a tool SMBUtil for linux, what is the equivalent in Windows ?

Comment: SMB doesn't have a name resolution function. Are you confusing it with NetBIOS? LLMNR? mDNS?

Comment: if you read the messages of the protocol, when I, from machine A, target machine B using its IP Address, it will reply to me with its Hostname (since it knows it), This way i can know the hostname of machine B without using DNS/Netbios. Thats what i meant, so no need to minus my question, just ask for clarification from me :)

Comment: I used https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsProtocolTestSuites but I thought that there is a tool that exist somewhere that is already compiled

Comment: Its my question and my comment, i was not asking about possible or not, i was asking about testing. I am a top notch developer and i imlplemented a world leading ip resolver component, the users that commemted here lack the out of the box think.

Comment: [citation needed]

Answer (score 3):

Your premise is flawed.
SMB is a file/print-sharing protocol.
It doesn't do name-resolution at all.
It relies on the normal name-resolution mechanisms like DNS, mDNS (Bonjour), PeerNameResolving (PNRP), NetBios or WINS, to name a few possible solutions.

You may be confused because WINS/NetBios can be done by the Samba server, but it isn't actually part of SMB.

Comment: if you read the messages of the protocol, when I, from machine A, target machine B using its IP Address, it will reply to me with its Hostname (since it knows it), This way i can know the hostname of machine B without using DNS/Netbios. Thats what i meant, so no need to minus my question, just ask for clarification from me :)